# Why does updating a set with map object destroy the map object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

The following code shown below:

```
y=set()
y.update([1])
x=map(chr, [65, 66, 67, 68])
for ch in x:
    print(ch)
print(y)
```

Outputs:

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> D
>
> {1}

Which is expected. However, when I update the `y` set with the `x` map object, it destroys the map object. This is shown here with this code:

```
y=set()
y.update([1])
x=map(chr, [65, 66, 67, 68])
y.update(x)
for ch in x:
    print(ch)
print(y)
```

which outputs:

> {'C', 1, 'D', 'A', 'B'}

When my expected output is this:

> A
>
> B
>
> C
>
> D
>
> {'C', 1, 'D', 'A', 'B'}

The variable x is no longer there and destroyed?

Can someone explain this please?

and also how do I keep the `x` map object after updating the `y` set?

Comment: A `map` object can only be iterated once. If you want to iterate it multiple times, transform it to a list. `x = list(map(...))`

Comment: @khelwood ah didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `map` would return a list. In Python 3, it returns a special kind of object, which can only be iterated once.

If you want to iterate it multiple times, you can transform it to a list.

```
x = list(map(chr, [65, 66, 67, 68]))
```